# How to select two tables and determine if the data is < or =

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form and one db with 2 tables.  Db tables are user-info and books.

user-info table -
id
title
author

books table -
id
title
copies

I'm populating the select box with the book titles with no problem.
The 2 tables have two columns that are the same - title.

The 2 tables have two columns that are the same - title.

What I need is find the number of titles in user-info table and compare it to the copies column in the books table. If user-info table column title is == to books table column copies, do not display that title in the select box.

For Example: This is an example to show what I'm trying to say.
user-info table column - title - the-title-of-a-book - there's 3 of this title. The books table column - copies - there's  3 copies left.  Since 3 == 3 the-title-of-a-book would not display in the select box.

I can't seem to figure this out.  Is there a better way to do this?

Here's what I have to populate the select box.

```
<select name="books">
<option value="">Select a Book</option>

<?php

mysqli_select_db($con,"books");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM books");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo ("<option value='$row[title]'>$row[title]</option>");
}

?>
</select>
```

Comment: What data is in the database?  As in the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your question:

```
<select name="books">
<option value="">Select a Book</option>

<?php
mysqli_select_db( $con,"books" );


// fetch titles from table user-info
$user_books = mysqli_query( $con,"SELECT title FROM user-info" );

// put the records into the array
$books = [ ];
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $user_books ) )
{
  if( isset( $books[$row[ 'title' ] ] ) )
  {
     $books[ $row[ 'title' ] ]++;
  } else {
     $books[ $row[ 'title' ] ] = 1;
  }
}

$result = mysqli_query( $con,"SELECT * FROM books" );

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) )
{
  // if the number of title in user table equals to the number of copies
  if( isset( $books[ $row[ 'title' ] ] ) && $books[ $row[ 'title' ] ] == $row[ 'copies' ] ) {
    continue;
  }
  echo ("<option value='" . $row[ 'title' ] . "'>" . $row[ 'title' ] . "</option>");
}

?>
</select>
```